# Are there any concrete application of the Lyapunov theorem for LTI systems?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Consider a LTI system $\dot x = Ax$.

This system is globally asymptotical stable iff given any $Q \succ 0$, there exists a unique $P \succ 0$ such that $A^{T}P+PA+Q=0$ holds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation

This is a neat theorem, however, it seems that it is much fast just to call $\text{eigs}(A)$ in MATLAB and check the sign of the eigenvalues rather than finding two PD matrices. So I don't get why I need to know something like this.

Is there any concrete application arising from Lyapunov equation for LTI systems?

If not, where else does it show up in dynamical system theory or control theory?

Comment: Sometimes a Lyapunov function is needed ($x^T P x$). It can be used to estimate the overshoot, for example.

Comment: Using a Lyapunov function is a general method for determining if an equilibrium is stable. When applied to linear systems you end up with the Lyapunov equation you have above. If you have a general nonlinear system you don't have eigenvalues, so this method doesn't apply (other than getting local stability results). Also, the matrix P gives you information about the shape of the level sets of your Lyapunov function. Depending on the problem this might have a physical meaning, e.g., it tells you the amount of energy in the system at different states and how the energy changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many applications. For instance,

- it allows you to derive tests to establish the stability of a system for which the matrix $A$ is uncertain (robust analysis). This can be used to design controllers for uncertain linear systems (robust control).
- it allows you to design controllers that can optimize certain properties of the closed-loop system using optimization-based methods.
- it allows you to prove the stability of certain important complex control methods such as Model Predictive Control, for instance.
- it allows you to establish the stability of more complex linear systems such as time-varying, parameter-varying, hybrid, and stochastic systems.